# How do plants absorb CO2?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I see many repeated claims that plants absorb $CO_2$ from the air.

$CO_2$ goes into the stomata, while $H_2O$ evaporates and leaves those same stomata. The $CO_2$ dissolves in the water in the plant sap, and then goes to wherever it's needed.

It occurred to me that in loose moist topsoil, there is a tremendous surface area for $CO_2$ to leave air and get into the water. And that water does get absorbed by plant roots. Meanwhile there is plentiful O2 that soil bacteria can use to oxidize organic matter in the soil and convert it to $CO_2$. In my imagination, this looks like a far more efficient way to collect $CO_2$. Instead of wait for the $CO_2$ from decaying organic matter to diffuse out of the soil into the air above and then enter stomata and dissolve in water there, cut out the diffusion step. The rising sap would carry $CO_2$ to wherever it will be used.

It seems to me this would be easy to test. Grow plants in sealed containers with their stems sticking through small holes in an impervious barrier. Introduce $CO_2$ containing $C_{14}$ either into the air above with the leaves, or into the air below with the soil the roots are in. Observe which way gets more $CO_2$ incorporated into the plants.

Have experiments like this been done? My quick search did not find experiments like that. It found only the many-times-repeated claim that plants absorb $CO_2$ through their stomata.

Comment: Carrying CO2 "in the sap" is not that easy of a step, especially compared to simple diffusion: as plants do not significantly decrease the local CO2 level, diffusion is basically a free pump insuring constant CO2 concentration. Furthermore, while CO2 does dissolve into the water, its concentration is rather low naturally. (Natural fluids that transport CO2 in large quantities, such as blood, have enzyme like carbonic anhydridase to create bicarbonate for mass transport; which soil water won't have.). Also, it maybe possible to disprove this theory by just cutting a leave and using the c14.

Comment: You see many repeated statements (not claims) that plants absorb CO2 from the air through the stomata of their leaves. For example, you can read an account of this in [Lodish et al., Molecualr Cell Biology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21472/#A4502). This is because the phenomena has been studied by numerous professional scientists for over 50 years. Your question shows a lack of the research required before posting on this list. If you had done that you might have discovered that typical experiments use (rootless) leaves and manipulate the CO2 concentration. I have voted to close.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This link shows that plants absorb CO2 in the mesophyll, from the air space. Water from the xylem evaporates into this space and leaves through stomata; this drives the movement of water from the roots. O2 created by plants also leaves through stomata. It does not show that the CO2 comes only through stomata and not with the water. Using rootless leaves would prevent roots from collecting CO2, though. Still, normal photosynthesis with no root and only normal CO2 air levels would plausibly say that CO2 from air is enough.

Comment: Eliane B, thank you for responding. I think that since CO2 level in soil air can reach as high as 8% during wheat cultivation, it seems plausible to me that plants might find a way to sequester that resource rather than just let it diffuse into the outer air and then concentrate it again from there. And that probably happens. https://www.nature.com/articles/415451a

Answer (score 2):

For most terrestrial plants, assimilation of soil inorganic carbon seems to be quite low. This may be because RuBisCO, the carbon assimilating enzyme, is generally [more of a limiting factor](https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-9422(81)85134-5) than CO<sub>2</sub> diffusion.

[Ford et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1093/treephys/27.3.375) found that "soil DIC [dissolved inorganic carbon] contributed ~0.8% to whole-plant C gain, and ~1.6% to belowground C gain" in seedlings of *Pinus taeda* exposed to <sup>13</sup>C-labeled soil DIC. [Ubierna et al. (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1093/treephys/tpp089) observed no contamination in leaf CO<sub>2</sub> efflux by <sup>13</sup>C-enriched soil watering of large conifers, despite showing that the water was taken up by the trees. However, [Bloemen et al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2012.04366.x) did observe assimilation of labeled carbon directly infused into the stems of poplar trees.

Some [aquatic plants](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1399-3054.1971.tb01436.x) in certain habitats may be adapted to assimilate much more carbon via their roots.

Plant physiology is a rich and mature field, and isotope analyses are a primary tool with a long history. Additionally, CO<sub>2</sub> and other gas exchange can be directly [measured across leaf surfaces](https://www.licor.com/env/products/photosynthesis/LI-6800/).

The carbon flux between the soil and the rhizosphere is [complex and bi-directional](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11104-009-9925-0), but overall, more carbon is generally lost through the roots than absorbed.

There are also dozens, or probably hundreds, of studies labeling leaves or above-ground material in various ways and tracking the fate of those elements, of which [this](https://www.istrc.org/images/Documents/Symposiums/Seventh/7th_symposium_proceedings_0066.pdf) is just one.

Comment: Thank you! I'm an amateur at this and my quick lit searches didn't find this.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to David's comment above, I learned enough vocabulary to do a better lit search.

Yes, $CO_2$ supplied to roots is absorbed and distributed by the xylem to places where it is photosynthesized. [This is not in doubt.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11550813_Characteristics_of_C4_photosynthesis_in_stems_and_petioles_of_C3_flowering_plants)

The remaining question is how much of the $CO_2$ used by plants comes through stomata from the outside air (where it is present in concentration around 0.04%), and how much of it comes to roots from subsurface air (where it is present in concentration that varies widely, up to [8%](https://dl.sciencesocieties.org/publications/sssaj/abstracts/47/6/SS0470061139)).

Answer (score -2):

The water in the plant absorbs Co2 from the air, Co2 dissolved in water equals H2CO3 carbonic acid, but carbonic acid is an extremely weak acid since it does not ionize sufficiently to produce a very high hydrogen-ion concentration. Glucose production from Co2 & pure H2O requires an electron to be in two places at the same time, absorbing light energy by this electron, de-crystalizes some of the electron working-mass that is responsible for rearranging Co2 & H2O into the crystaline C6H12O6-glucose molecule. The process of photosynthesis is one of "particle-flow" within a plant molecule and molecular bulk-flow within that same plant is a process of respiration. Respiration must also have a working-mass as well, H2O is one of the primary open-loop vehicles and light is the other primary open-loop vehicle that drives the closed-looped function of a plant. Being the difference between the interference of particle-flow in an inertial frame of reference, and the interference of the acceleration & de-acceleration of bulk-flow in a non-inertial frame of reference. Photosynthesis has similar characteristics as a alternating current transformer, they both are frequency dependent and use electrons to drive the machinery that absorbs & transforms Co2 with other molecules.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. ——— Answers should directly and clearly address the original question — yours is very hard to follow (try adding some formatting and make sure you read the entire question). Answers are also much more likely to receive a favorable response when they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, answers are indistinguishable from opinion and thus are inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @user62753, one way the CO2 diffuses into stomata and inside the leaf the exposed water dissolves CO2 which is then converted to something else that's easier stored. The other way, CO2 would diffuse into water adsorbed onto soil particles and then be taken in by roots where it would be converted into the same transport molecules. It makes sense to me it would happen both ways. The CO2 concentration in the upper air is 0.04%, while the CO2 concentration in the air near roots can reach 8%. My claim is testable, it has been tested, and it is true.