# What part, roughly, of the carbon in a plant comes from the soil? As opposed to the atmosphere?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

[C4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_carbon_fixation) plants contain a slightly higher percentage of carbon-13 than [C3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_carbon_fixation) plants. Is this because of carbon obtained from the soil or the atmosphere?

I have read that plants using different chemical pathways, such as millet and wheat, incorporate distinctive proportions of stable carbon isotopes *from the SOIL*.

Do C4 plants need more carbon-13, or does that process just happen to result in accumulation of more carbon-13?

Comment: Always good to cite things you've read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do plants absorb CO2?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76031/how-do-plants-absorb-co2)

Answer (score 11):

Only a small fraction of plant carbon is soil-derived: e.g. from [Majlesi et al 2019](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.est.8b06089):

> although the majority of plant C was obtained from atmosphere by photosynthesis, a significant portion (up to 3–5%) of C in plant roots was derived from old soil

(in an experiment with Scots pine and reed canary grass).

As laid out by this [review of C4 photosynthesis](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/pdf/S0960-9822(13)00507-1.pdf) (Kellogg 2013), the primary reason for differential isotopic make-up of C3 and C4 plants is that the biochemical pathways they use fractionate isotopes differently — not because the plants' requirements are different.

> Because of the very different
> affinities of Rubisco and PEP
> carboxylase for CO$_2$ , C$_3$ and C$_4$ plants
> differ in the carbon isotopes that they
> assimilate. While most atmospheric
> CO$_2$is made up of ${}^{12}$C, a small fraction
> includes ${}^{13}$C. Rubisco has a fairly high
> $K_m$ and hence low affinity for CO$_2$, and preferentially fixes ${}^{12}$C. The ratio of ${}^{13}$C
> to ${}^{12}$C ($\delta^{13}$C) in a C$_3$ plant is thus much
> lower than the ratio in the atmosphere;
> the carbon in structural and storage
> carbohydrates contains much less
> ${}^{13}$C. PEP carboxylase has a lower
> $K_m$ for CO$_2$ than Rubisco and hence
> a higher affinity; as a consequence it
> discriminates much less against ${}^{13}$C
> than Rubisco does, so that the $\delta^{13}$C
> is appreciably closer to atmospheric.

---

Kellogg, Elizabeth A. 2013. “C4 Photosynthesis.” Current Biology 23 (14): R594–99. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2013.04.066.

Majlesi, Soroush, Jukka Juutilainen, Anne Kasurinen, Promise Mpamah, Tatiana Trubnikova, Markku Oinonen, Pertti Martikainen, and Christina Biasi. “Uptake of Soil-Derived Carbon into Plants: Implications for Disposal of Nuclear Waste.” Environmental Science & Technology 53, no. 8 (April 16, 2019): 4198–4205. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.est.8b06089.